# EWS signature updation error

Tags: exchangewebservices, signature

```
public void updateSignature(ExchangeService exchange, String signature) {
    try {
        FolderId f = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root);
        UserConfiguration user = UserConfiguration.bind(exchange,
                "OWA.UserOptions", f, UserConfigurationProperties.All);

        if (user.getDictionary().containsKey("signaturetext"))
            user.getDictionary().setElements("signaturetext", signature);
        else
            user.getDictionary().addElement("signaturetext", signature);
        user.update();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception for user.update(); I am able to print the old signature in the console before setting the new one and also the new one after setting it in the dictionary. But, I am not able to update the changes permanently. Thanks in advance
.

Answer (score 0):

in the others code it's using root.parentFolderId not root. 
maybe it's that problem:

attached the code

```
static void SetSigniture(ExchangeService service) throws Exception {
    Folder Root = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Root);
    UserConfiguration OWAConfig = UserConfiguration.bind(service, "OWA.UserOptions", Root.getParentFolderId(), UserConfigurationProperties.All);
    String hsHtmlSigniture = "<img src='http://www.baidu.com/img/baidu_jgylogo3.gif' />";
    String stTextSig = "Text sig";
    System.out.println(OWAConfig.getDictionary().getElements("timezone"));;
    if (OWAConfig.getDictionary().containsKey("signaturehtml")) {
        OWAConfig.getDictionary().setElements("signaturehtml", new Object());
    } else {
        OWAConfig.getDictionary().addElement("signaturehtml", hsHtmlSigniture);
    }
    if (OWAConfig.getDictionary().containsKey("signaturetext")) {
        OWAConfig.getDictionary().setElements("signaturetext", stTextSig);
    } else {
        OWAConfig.getDictionary().addElement("signaturetext", stTextSig);
    }
    OWAConfig.update();
}
```